# Sums and Direct Sums

Tags: linear-algebra

My text says:

$$ U + W = \{(x,y,0):x,y ∈ F\}$$

if

$$U = \{(x,0,0) \in F^{3} : x ∈ F\}$$
   $$W = \{(0,y,0) \in F^{3} : y ∈ F\}$$

I have to verify this.

What I did was add $(x,0,0)$ and$ (y,0,0)$ together: $(x+0,0+y,0+0)$ and got $(x,y,0)$. Is that enough or there is more to it?

Comment: :notice definition  of Direct Sums is $U + W = \{(x+y:x ∈ U,y\in W\}$ and you can easily conclude$ U + W = \{(x,y,0):x,y ∈ F\}$

Comment: so just showing the addition is enough to prove it?

Comment: and you must showing $\dim U+\dim W=\dim(U+W)$  or $U\cap W=\{0\}$

Comment: @Grigor OK, I think I understand what you mean. You of course should verify $U\cap W=\{0\}$ (or verify every element of $U+W$ has a unique expression of the form $u+w,u\in U, w\in W$ )so that the sum is a direct sum.

Comment: @wxu: The question doesn't say anything about direct sums. The title does, though, which is kind of confusing...

Comment: it belongs to direct sum section.. the method is direct sum i guess

Comment: linear algebra, kinda, doesn't make much sense to me.. it's a big picture which I see in parts. Can anyone point me to a good book to read, that actually makes sense and shows how everything is related?

Comment: @Grigor: this question has been asked already, for example here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143904/linear-algebra-text or here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4335/where-to-start-learning-linear-algebra .

Comment: that's why I didn't ask the question as a new question... just a comment on the side to be pointed to the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an exercise, it's a very basic one, so I would guess you are expected to do it carefully, that is, take any element of $\{(x,y,0):x,y ∈ F\}$, and show that it belongs in $U+W$ and vice versa, explicitly writing out what you are doing and why.

If the text just says that you should verify something, then I would say that it's enough to just convince yourself that it is true and that you know how to prove it, so that would probably be enough.

Comment: It's the second, text wants me to verify.